# Can instincts disappear after a long period of non-usefulness?

Tags: behaviour, epigenetics, instinct

I recently dived into the topic of **instincts** and now I have a question, where I haven't found anything about.

There's this thesis (I think mentioned [here](https://link.springer.com/article/10.3758/BF03200077) amongst others) that, through epigenetics, learned instincts **can** be passed along in genes and **can** over time be permanently integrated into the genome.

But...

Why is there no mentioning about how instincts can disappear over time, if they're simply not useful anymore? Or is it just not possible?

Comment: If its like any other genetic trait, there needs to be selective pressure for it to be counter-productive to be weeded out. Merely not being useful is not necessarily sufficient. though I suppose over *extremely* long periods of time it may get diluted out by mutation if it presents no beneficial or ill consequences.

Comment: @DKNguyen - That would make a good answer.

Comment: OP: The [Russian fox farm experiment](https://evolution-outreach.biomedcentral.com/articles/10.1186/s12052-018-0090-x) would give you a lot of information on the loss of instinctive behavior through selective pressure.

Comment: @anongoodnurse That's super interesting. I had no idea there was an experiment being run like that and with such definitive results showing themselves so quickly.

Comment: @DKNguyen - A solid example of your very on-point  answer. The back story of the experiment is also very interesting. :)

Comment: so basically how does the evolution of behavior work. simple question do you know  how tissues or organs are lost in evolution

Comment: @John what does that have to do with behavior?

Comment: Because behaviors are lost in the same way, it can take a long time to lose a an organ or tissue if it has no direct detriment. it is lost through drift.

Comment: oh, thanks. very interesting. I guess, I'll read into that somewhere soon

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If it is like any other genetic trait, it will only be weeded out if there exists selective pressure that makes it counter-productive. Merely not being useful is not necessarily sufficient. Though I suppose over extremely long periods of time, it may get diluted out by mutation and propagation of those mutations if it persists in having no beneficial or detrimental effects.